# Looking for the Last Cell that Meets Critera(Horizontally)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, lambda, formula, lookup

I am trying to find a way in Google Sheets to return the last cell based on certain criteria. I've included the table below:

|  | Jan | Feb | March | April | LATEST SALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group 1 | sale | sale | no sale | sale | April |
| group 2 | no sale | no sale | sale | no sale | March |

I am trying to have the "LATEST SALE" Column return the values I listed above: "April, "March", but I am having trouble finding the right formula.

I know there is a lookup and sort formula, something like

```
=LOOKUP(H2,SORT(B2:D2),SORT(B1:D1,B2:D2,TRUE))
```

Perhaps there is something for a horizontal lookup and sort? Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(BYROW(B2:E, LAMBDA(x, LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(x="sale")), B1:E1))))
```

[image]

---

if you want to drag it use:

```
=IFNA(LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(B2:E2="sale")), B$1:E$1))
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for your quick reply. I wrote your formula in cell F2 and it worked, but when I drag the formula down , it doesn't work and created a #REF! in cell F2. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: @KevinL this is not a dragging formula. you should use it in top row and formula should auto-populate for all rows. see picture reference

Comment: Ahh, I see. I apologize, I was not aware of that. Thanks for your help. I'm marking this as solved.
Thank you!